# Azure AD OAuth2 SSO Silent authentication

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I am trying to have users silently authenticated using Microsoft Azure AD OAuth2. I  am calling this url in an IFrame for my online website:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?prompt=none&response_type=code&client_id=XXXXX-XXX&scope=openid profile offline_access User.ReadBasic.All
```

If the user is logged in this works perfectly on all browsers and returns the authorization code.

However for domain joined machines this does not work for IE & Edge, but does on Chrome..?
For IE & Edge the authorize page returns `error=interaction_required`. When the `prompt=none` is removed however from the url and called in a new browser tab it authenticates without any interaction though..

Why do IE & Edge require interaction on domain joined machines, when it apparently does not need it and Chrome works completely fine?

Answer (score 0):

An educated guess is that this behavior is enforced to avoid delivering tokens to applications without the user explicitly being aware of it. iframe-based applications differ from a regular web applications because the former have inherently more security risks associated with them in the form of click-jacking https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking.